# Excel VBA: How do I set this variable as a range of cells that I can call from the worksheet one after another in this for loop?

Tags: vba, excel

How do I set this variable as a range of cells that I can call from the worksheet one after another in this for loop? I get "invalid use of property and can't get past j ="Range...

This is Holzer's method for finding natural frequency of a torsional system. I want to take the range from j k and w below and send it through the loop and have it display "i" "theta" and "torque" after each iteration in next cell. The code is below.

```
Option Explicit


Sub TorsionalVibrationAnalysis_()
    Dim n As Integer 'position along stucture
    Dim m As Integer
    Dim i As Long 'frequency to be used
    Dim j As ListColumn 'moment of inertia
    Dim k As ListColumn 'stiffness
    Dim theta As Long 'angular displacement
    Dim torque As ListRow 'torque
    Dim lambda As Long 'ListRow 'omega^2
    Dim w As ListColumn

    'equations relating the displacement and torque


    n = 1
    j = Range("d2:f2").Value 'Range("d2:f2").Value
    k = Range("d3:f3").Value
        'initial value
    w = Range("B1:B30").Value

    For i = 1 To 30

         'start at 40 and increment frequency by 20
        w = 40 + (i - 1) * 20

        lambda = w ^ 2

        theta = 1

        torque = lambda * j(1)

        m = n + 1

        'j(m),k(n)

        theta = theta - torque(i, n) / k(n)

        torque(i, m) = torque(i, n) + lambda * j(m) * theta

        If m = 4 & i < 30 Then

            w(i) = 40 + (i - 1) * 20

            lambda = w(i) ^ 2

            ElseIf m = 4 & i >= 30 Then

            Cells([d], [5+i]).display (i)
            Cells([e], [5+i]).display (theta)
            Cells([f], [5+i]).display (torque)

            End If

                If m <> 4 Then

                n = n + 1

            End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Try setting j as variant not ListColumn.

Comment: Or if `j` is an object (`ListColumn` is a `Range` object), then you must use `Set j = ...` to assign it.

Comment: Okay I set j as variant and got past that point. Not im trying to call the first value of j as seen in the code below: torque = lambda * j(1) but i get an error "subscript out of range". How do I call cell d2 properly?

Comment: `j` is a two-dimensional array (1 to 1, 1 to 3), so if you wanted the value from D2 that would be `j(1, 1)`  F2 would be `j(1, 3)`

Comment: Thanks Tim. That seemed to work!

Comment: Okay there is a bunch of other issues with this code that I'll work on myself for now, but I want to mark my two questions as answered. How do I do that?